# Programmatically add an attribute to a method or parameter

Tags: c#, attributes, typedescriptor

I can use TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes to add an attribute to a type in runtime. How do I do the same for a method and parameter? (maybe 2 separate questions...)

Comment: In what situations do you want the attributes to appear?

Comment: For reflection, hence I noticed even TypeDescriptor.AddAttribute doesnt work for that.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`TypeDescriptor.AddAttributes` only affects a *very* specific use-case; i.e. from within `System.ComponentModel`. For the *rest* of reflection, it knows *nothing* about the extra attribute. And indeed, `System.ComponentModel` doesn't really apply to methods or parameters.

So in short; you can't. You will need to store this information somewhere else (bespoke), or add it at compile-time.

Comment: @Mark Gravell, Any workaround to add property-metadata in a Silverlight project (where `TypeDescriptor` and `TypeDescriptionProvider` aren't implemented?

Comment: @Shimmy not as far as I know, no.

Comment: @Shimmy btw - if you're going to flag something as a duplicate, please say "of what" (in fact, there's a vote-type just for that)

Comment: @MarcGravell, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2397617/75500) is a duplicate of [your answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2397585/75500), which you posted 9 minutes earlier.

Comment: @MarcGravell, as per my issue, first let me describe what is my actual case. I have a `User` class that implements `IUser` on the server. The generated client-entity implement `IIdentity.IsAuthenticated`, and I wanted to attribute it with `[Display(AutoGenerateField=false)]`. I tried to make a matching dummy property on server and mark it with `Exclude` so it's not generated twice, then add metadata for it in the metadata body class, the metadata should be generated for the existing property on the client as well, but that didn't work. Generated `IsAuthenticated` remains unattributed on client

Answer (score 0):

As I see from analyzing the `TypeDescriptor` class in Reflector, the `.AddAttributes` method internally calls the `.AddProvider` method. The `TypeDescriptionProvider` instance passed to it is actually responsible for providing meta-data. You could try adding the [TypeDescriptionProviderAttribute] attribute to your class and implement your own provider by deriving from the `TypeDescriptionProvider` class. As the documentation says, by overriding `TypeDescriptionProvider.CreateInstance`, you could provide a substitute object whose type has all necessary attributes. I suspect that the attributes applied to methods inside the substitution type will also take effect. However, I haven't tried that myself, so feel free to experiment...