# Is it possible to change the DescriptionAttribute value of an inherited DependencyProperty in a derived class?

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties, derived-class, inherited

If I create a class that extends `UserControl` and want to set a default value for a `DependencyProperty` that is declared in `UserControl`, say `FontSize`, I can add a static constructor like the following:

```
static MyUserControl()
{
    UserControl.FontSizeProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MyUserControl), 
new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(28.0));
}
```

Before I learned about the `OverrideMetadata` method, I used to override the property and set the `DescriptionAttribute` in the following way:

```
public new static readonly DependencyProperty FontSizeProperty = 
DependencyProperty.Register("FontSize", typeof(double), typeof(MyUserControl), 
new PropertyMetadata(28.0));

[Description("My custom description."), Category("Text")]
public new double FontSize
{
    get { return (double)GetValue(FontSizeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(FontSizeProperty, value); }
}
```

The `DescriptionAttribute` value is displayed as a popup tooltip in the Properties Window of Visual Studio when a user moves the mouse pointer over the relevant property name. My question is, is it possible to set the `DescriptionAttribute` value of this `DependencyProperty` in a similar way to overriding the metadata? Or will I have to keep the CLR getter/setter property and attribute declaration?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you actually asking whether you can change the value of an Attribute, which is in the current assembly, at runtime? Because if so: no, you cannot do that because the attributes are stored with the metadata in the assembly and remain there, statically.

Comment: @DaveClemmer, please refrain from making pointless edits. Swapping the [tag:dependency-property] tag to [tag:dependency-properties] was a pointless edit and should have been rejected.

Comment: @Sheridan, first of all this was done quite a long time ago, second this was part of a tag cleanup effort to reduce duplicate tags and improve search, third by changing the tag back to dependency-property, you have created a duplicate tag again (that someone will probably remove again), and finally you have reduced your score in the dependency-properties tag that is actually being used.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found that I could access the `DescriptionAttribute` value of the inherited type property, but only from an instance constructor and not the static constuctor because I needed a reference to the control object. Also, I could not set it using this method as it was a read only property:

```
AttributeCollection attributes = 
    TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(this)["FontSize"].Attributes;
DescriptionAttribute attribute = 
    (DescriptionAttribute)attributes[typeof(DescriptionAttribute)];
attribute.Description = "Custom description"; // not possible - read only property
```

I then discovered that you can't change declared attribute values at run time from these articles:

1. [Can attributes be added dynamically in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/129285/can-attributes-be-added-dynamically-in-c)
2. [Programmatically add an attribute to a method or parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397519/programmatically-add-an-attribute-to-a-method-or-parameter)

I will therefore continue to declare the CLR wrapper properties with new `DescriptionAttribute` values and override the metadata in the static constructor just to set new default values.